# How do I make matplotlib line graphs in my TKinter app interactive?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been making an application that uses matplotlib to make a line graph, but the issue I've been having is that when I try and hover over the graph, it is a static image that I can pan around, but I'm unable to get the values on my graph when I hover my mouse. I'm not looking to make a scatter graph, but a line graph that annotates over the values when I hover my mouse over it. I understand that matplotlib graphs can be made interactive with Dash/Plotly, but the issue is that they only work on webapps, and I am looking for a way to make my mpl graph look more like a plotly one on a Tk GUI app. Any way that this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding the toolbar (`matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.NavigationToolbar2Tk`) to your plot? It shows the coordinates of the mouse on the right, like in a regular matplotlib plot (I mean not embedded in a tkinter app)